# Mostrar valor ao invés do id da chave estrangeira no Django Rest Framework

Tags: angular, api, django, django-rest-framework

Model

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

user_agent = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

def __str__(self):
   return self.name
```

VIEWS

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.views.decorators.csrf import csrf_exempt
from rest_framework.parsers import JSONParser
from django.http.response import JsonResponse

from devedor.models import Debtor, Employees

from devedor.serializers import DebtorSerializer, EmployeesSerializer

from django.core.files.storage import default_storage


##def

@csrf_exempt
def debtorAPI(request,id=0):
    if request.method=='GET':
        debtors = Debtor.objects.all()
        debtors_serializer = DebtorSerializer(debtors, many= True)
        return JsonResponse(debtors_serializer.data, safe=False)
```

SerializerS

```
from django.db.models import fields
from rest_framework import serializers

from devedor.models import Debtor, Employees

class DebtorSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
   class Meta:
       model = Debtor
       fields = (
                'IdDebtor',
                'name',
                'id_tax',
                'id_espaider',
                'contabil',
                'risco',
                'wallet_type',
                'phone_1',
                'phone_2',
                'phone_hot',
                'phone_whatsapp',
                'status_negociacao',
                'user_agent',
                'cpc_status',
                'data_alteracao',
                'observacoes_status',
                'cpc_status',
                'observacoes_status'
       )
```

ESTÁ RETORNANDO

```
  {
        "IdDebtor": 1,
        "name": "William Marques",
        "id_tax": "001.255.481-29",
        "id_espaider": "21223",
        "contabil": "53452344.00",
        "risco": "4654361.00",
        "wallet_type": "MASSIFICADO PF",
        "phone_1": "51991736242",
        "phone_2": "51991736242",
        "phone_hot": "51991736242",
        "phone_whatsapp": "51991736242",
        "status_negociacao": "PROPOSTA APROVADA",
        **"user_agent": 3,**  PRECISO RETORNAR O NOME ----
        "cpc_status": "SIM",
        "data_alteracao": "2021-08-24T18:51:01.235021Z",
        "observacoes_status": "paris to paris"
    }
]
```

Answer (score 0):

Para ter informações de um outro modelo, você pode aninhar os serializers. Aninhar serializers é mais fácil do que parece. Vou dar um exemplo geral, e você pode se aprofundar mais [nessa documentação.](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/#nested-relationships)

Aninhar é quando você tem um modelo, que tem que ser "chamado", na serialização de outro modelo.

O serializer do modelo que deve ser "puxado" deve ser declarado antes. Logo abaixo dele, o serializer do modelo que você quer usar como principal, deve chamar o serializer de cima(do modelo a ser "puxado"), e adicioná-lo aos fields. Esse exemplo vem da documentação.

```
class TrackSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Track
        fields = ['order', 'title', 'duration']

class AlbumSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    tracks = TrackSerializer(many=True, read_only=True)


    class Meta:
        model = Album
        fields = ['album_name', 'artist', 'tracks']
```

Many serve para receber mais de um valor, e o read_only pode ser desativado caso você crie e atualize seus modelos dentro do serializer.

Veja, o AlbumSerializer "chama" o serializer secundário, a resposta desse serializer vai ser incluída como um field normal. Como eu disse, é uma ideia geral, mas ela pode ser aplicada ao seu problema.

Answer (score 0):

Uma forma simples e prática para retornar seria:

Adicionar uma property ao seu models:

```
@property
def user_agent_nome(self):
    return self.user_agent.nome
```

Adicionar o novo campo "user_agent_nome" ao seus fields do DebtorSerializer.